# django update database based on pk

Tags: python, django

I apologise for not being explicit in my earlier question. Below is the updated question.

I am working with django on `updating` my `QueryDict` into the database. This `QueryDict` comes from a `request.POST` method via the `html` interface.

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['foo'], 'student_attend': ['Select', 'Select', 'Select'], 'final_student_pk': ['7', '8', '12'], 'submit_student_attendance': ['']}>
```

What I was attempting to do, was to update my `database object` `student_attend` column based on the `final_student_pk` value. Meaning to say, I was attempting the below:

```
if 'submit_student_attendance' in request.POST:
    to_update = AddNewSchedule.objects.filter(pk=request.POST['final_student_pk'])
    to_update.update(student_attend=request.POST['student_attend'])
```

This does do the job of updating my `AddNewSchedule` database table. However, it only updates the last `pk` item. (ie: it only updates item 12 in the database). It does not loop through `pk 7` and `pk8` to update the database as well.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide the actual code that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: That code is already correctly unpacking the dict

Comment: Your code work as expected you know?

Comment: Hello, sorry for not being explicit in my earlier question. I have updated my question with actual code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

works for me?

```
>>> a = {'a': 1, 'b': [2,3]}
>>> for k, v in a.items():
...     print(v)
...     print(k)
...
1
a
[2, 3]
b
```